# Flutter app can't run on real device or emulator

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator

I am new at Flutter. I am getting trouble with running flutter project.

**Problem:**

> Not applicable for the "main.dart" configuration shown in device selection[image]

After Running the project shown bellow exception in the console.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
               > Connect to download.flutter.io:80 [download.flutter.io/172.217.167.144] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
               > Connect to download.flutter.io:80 [download.flutter.io/172.217.167.144] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
               > Connect to download.flutter.io:80 [download.flutter.io/172.217.167.144] failed: Connection timed out: connect
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:armeabi_v7a_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:armeabi_v7a_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/armeabi_v7a_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/armeabi_v7a_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
               > Connect to download.flutter.io:80 [download.flutter.io/172.217.167.144] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:armeabi_v7a_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/armeabi_v7a_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/armeabi_v7a_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
               > Connect to download.flutter.io:80 [download.flutter.io/172.217.167.144] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:armeabi_v7a_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/armeabi_v7a_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/armeabi_v7a_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
               > Connect to download.flutter.io:80 [download.flutter.io/172.217.167.144] failed: Connection timed out: connect
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/x86_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/x86_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
               > Connect to download.flutter.io:80 [download.flutter.io/172.217.167.144] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/x86_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/x86_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
               > Connect to download.flutter.io:80 [download.flutter.io/172.217.167.144] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/x86_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/x86_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
               > Connect to download.flutter.io:80 [download.flutter.io/172.217.167.144] failed: Connection timed out: connect
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
               > Connect to download.flutter.io:80 [download.flutter.io/172.217.167.144] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
               > Connect to download.flutter.io:80 [download.flutter.io/172.217.167.144] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.pom'.
               > Connect to download.flutter.io:80 [download.flutter.io/172.217.167.144] failed: Connection timed out: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 45s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Plugin For Flutter and Dart installed latest version. By running flutter doctor in cmd show all ok. here it is,

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Microsoft Windows
    [Version 10.0.18362.592], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    29.0.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

I don't understand where I mistake. Please help me if you know.

**Thanks for your help**

Comment: Show your main.dart file code

Comment: Default code provide by creating an Flutter Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to re install the SDK of flutter.
i have faced the same problem as well. then i re-installed the flutter SDK and everything went perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps:

1. GO TO PROJECT STRUCTURE>PROJECT>NOSDK
2. Change NOSDK to the latest ANDROID API PLATFORM
3. THEN GO TO MODULE DO THE SAME

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to execute an integrated test and it was missing to pass the flavor to the test command as well.

This command was throwing error: `flutter test integration_test/app_test.dart`

This command was passing: `flutter test integration_test/app_test.dart --flavor qa`